# segmentation of dataset where input and output divide by different timestep

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

```
def create_dataset(voltage, current, temp, ah):
    voltage = voltage[::sampling_interval]
    current = current[::sampling_interval]
    temp = temp[::sampling_interval]
    ah = ah[::sampling_interval]
    examples = len(voltage)
    data = []
    X, Y = [], []
    for i in range(examples):
        data.append(current[i])
        data.append(voltage[i])
        data.append(temp[i])
        data.append((ah[i] + max_capacity) / max_capacity)
    data = np.array(data)
    data = np.reshape(data, (examples, features + 1))
    data = data[:examples // timesteps * timesteps][:]
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        X.append(data[i][:features])
        Y.append(data[i][features:])
    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)
    return X, Y
```

in above code

voltage, current, temp is features here

ah is target OR output here

in above code I divided whole dataset from same timestep(=90)

But, now I want to divide input(current, voltage, temp) with different time step for ex 110 and output(ah) with different time step for ex 100.

I want to modify above code where input should divide by different timestep1 and output should divide by different timestep2.
Here X and Y returns  input and output.

what to do exactly for write code for that? kindly help me to write a exact code for above problem.

I want to do transformation to my dataset to make model better in term of speed and accuracy. so I want to make function there I want to divide my input with time step = 110 and divide my output with timestep =100, in above attempt I divided all dataset including input and output with same timestep = 90. but i am unable to modify above code where input should divide by different timestep and output should divide by different timestep.

I want to create an empty list then create a for loop, inside for loop divide the input and output with different timestep and append it to the empty list. kindly help me for writing code for this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider adding details like expected output, attempted approach and problems in that approach